# Random-shuffing python dataframe row between categories

Tags: python, dataframe

I am aware of the numpy.random.permutation method to conveniently shuffle the rows in a dataframe.

I want, however, the rows of one column to be shuffled such that after the shuffling, same values of this column are associated with the same values of a
second column. For instance here:

```
     sid  tid   cluster_id                   coherence
0    484  367          0   (-0.7602504647007313-0.12366326038519604j)
1    485  367          0   (-0.7602504647007313-0.12366326038519604j)
2    227    2          1   (0.8285282150429198+0.007917196582272277j)
3    228    2          1   (0.8285282150429198+0.007917196582272277j)
4    488  245          2   (-0.5247187752391191+0.03756613687159624j)
5    489  245          2   (-0.5247187752391191+0.03756613687159624j)
6     76  504          3   (-0.5017704895797781-0.17508351848297674j)
7     59  545          3  (-0.37153924345882344-0.08026706090664427j)
```

I want to shuffle the value of the rows of "coherence".

Right now, rows with identical tids also have the same coherence values.
**This should also remain after the shuffling - but the coherence values should be assigned to new tids.**

Hence a coherence value which was previously associated with a tid X will be
associated with a new tid Y, but all rows with this new tid Y should have this same coherence value.

Comment: If you shuffle _entire rows_, the coherence and tid should stick together.

Comment: They should be shuffled - they should NOT stick together. But the coherence values should be consistent for the NEW tid they get assigned to

Comment: Can you make the dataframe easy to copy?

Comment: I suggest you read the [mcve] before posting more questions, there is no example of what you want, what "you have tried", if at all, and not even enough code to recreate your dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm too lazy to reproduce your dataframe, I just use a toy case. What you want is to shuffle in a groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tid':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'others':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'coherence':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df['coherence'] = df.groupby('tid').coherence.transform(np.random.permutation)
```

**UPDATE**

Okay so I understood you wrong the first time, the previous answer shuffles within each group of `tid` but you want to shuffle the groups. Still the `groupby` is the solution, just shuffle the groups first:

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'tid':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'coherence':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})
groups = [df for _, df in df[['tid','coherence']].groupby('tid')]
random.shuffle(groups)
df[['tid', 'coherence']] = pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I hope this does it.

**UPDATE**

What you want is not clear from your question at all. Here's your solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tid':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'coherence':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})
tmp = df[['tid', 'coherence']].drop_duplicates()
tmp['coherence'] = np.random.permutation(tmp.coherence)
pd.merge(df, tmp, 'left', left_on='tid', right_on='tid')
```

`coherence_x` is the old one and `coherence_y` is the new one.

Comment: @Pegah Let me make sure I understand what you want first. You want that within every `tid`, only the `coherence` column to be shuffled, right? so if `coherence` 1 to 3 in my example are associated with `tid==1`, but after shuffling, they are not associated with their previous `others` anymore. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Hi - no, the coherence values should be shuffled between tids. So say we have a coherence value of 5 associated with tid1. After shuffling, the coherence value would for instance be assoicated with tid24, but all rows with tid24 would now have a coherence value of 5

Comment: @Pegah: So the coherence to tid is 1 to 1 correspondence?

Comment: Now there still is no shuffling between tid and coherence. So tid 1 is having the same coherence value even after shuffling, which is not correct. Tid 1 had coherence 1, but after shuffling it should be randomly assigned a new coherence value. But all the rows with tid = 1 should be assigned this (NEW) coherence value.